# Save and retrieve prettytable contents

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, prettytable

I'm using `prettytable` module for pretty printing. I'd like to know how to save the prettytable instances. I know how to print it to a file but I want to save it somewhere, like pickling, if that's possible. And later, I'd like to access these variables as well. Can anybody help me out?

My pretty table looks like the following:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

field_names = ["S.No", "username", "created_at", "result"]
tab = PrettyTable(field_names)
tab.padding_width = 1
tab.add_row([1, 'foo', '28-10-2016', 'Yes'])
tab.add_row([2, 'bar', '29-10-2016', 'Noo'])
```

But I'm appending lot more rows to the table sometimes it will be 100.
Ideally, I'd like to save the variable `tab` and at a later time access all the rows that I appended to `tab`.

How can I achieve this? Also, is it possible to access individual values like `tab[1][1]` which will give `bar` as output? I tried this but it didn't work. Instead the whole row is printed.

Comment: You can use pandas and iterate over its rows adding it to the table. The same way you can keep your dataframe as a variable

Comment: pickle should work. Show us an attempt.

Comment: I want it to be lightweight. Pandas is too heavy..

Answer (score 0):

You should just use pickle.

```
import pickle

pickle.dump( tab, open( "tab.p", "wb" ) )
```